# Minecraft in 64bit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I have Minecraft installed on a 64bit system but when I launch it run in 32bit so I uninstalled java 32bit so I just have java 64bit installed but now when I launch I get `No JVM could be found on your system` I am using Minecraft 1.5.2 and Windows 7 ultimate 64bit. Thanks if any one can help.

**Update:** If i completley uninstall java and then install java 64bit (offline) then i get this error: [image]

Comment: http://www.minecrafthasrunoutofmemory.com/installing-64-bit-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uninstall Java and reinstall the 64 bit version. But use the offline installer and not the online installer. Then it will work.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work see edits.

Comment: Just sorted it seemed to be the launcher.